# Why is this switch sparking?

Tags: switches, safety, spark

I have a [Vega 650 power supply](https://us.tdk-lambda.com/ftp/Specs/vega_var.pdf) which does not have a power switch.  So I wired a switch into the power cord.  When I flip the switch, there is about a 1 second delay, then the power supply fan turns on and the switch audibly clicks and sometimes visibly sparks.  I get about 1 - 3 audible clicks and 0 - 1 sparks.  The power supply is 120V 11A MAX but is not currently connected to any load.

I did have some difficulty soldering the copper wires to the aluminum contacts inside the switch housing.  I commonly find that solder flows nicely onto the copper but less so onto the aluminum.  Would a poor solder connection cause this?
[image: Inside of switch]
[image: Back of switch]

Comment: That doesn't look like an 11A switch. And the initial inrush is likely way more that 11A.

Comment: You cannot solder to aluminum. It must be plated first with nickel/tin.

Comment: @Trevor I will replace the switch with one that has an appropriate rating.

Comment: 2/250 ~ Means 2 A, 250 V rating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this switch sparking?

This is an inline switch for lighting. Intended for loads similar to one lighting armature.
Instead of a light of less than 1 Amp, you have attached an 11 Amp power supply.

The differences from lights are:
 - Your load has inrush current.
 - Your load is more than 10 times an old incandescent light.

Your switch is not intended for the load. Get a better switch.

Comment: An incandescent light also has a high inrush current; not as high as a 10A load, of course. It settles down as it heats up.

Answer (score 4):

The switch terminals are highly unlikely to be aluminum.  However, the "silver" plating on many switch and connector terminals is often very reluctant to accept solder - it takes extra flux, and some scraping of the terminal to make a good solder joint.

Comment: +1, but more and more products, especially wires, are now RoHS compatible which means they are nickel plated. You must crimp them to headers or pins that will solder to a PCB.

Answer (score 1):

It's sparking because the contacts are dirty or degraded, or because the wires aren't fully connected.

When the power supply wakes up it takes a big slurp of electric current and that surge is vaporising some fine structure into sparks.